# GridView with objectDataSource is returning NULL cell values in RowEditing and RowUpdating events

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I am using an ObjectDataSource with a GridView as shown below. It's wrapped in an UpdatePanel. When user presses a button outside this UpdatePanel, it should populate the gridview by feeding the ObjectSource Select method some seed values. That part is working fine - the gridView initializes successfully when the Select method is called. When the user proceeds to press the Edit button, the gridView also successfully transforms into edit mode with editable TextBox controls. That part also works fine, but I've tried to inspect the GridViewRow.Cell[i].Text and the GridViewRow.Cell[i].Controls[j] values during this transition and it is always NULL for every cell in the gridview.

Finally, when the Update methods are called on the underlying ObjectSource, all of the parameters passed into the Update method are effectively NULL. In short, even though the user sees the content of the cells, the code is never able to capture this content - it only receives NULL. Note, I implement several DataBinds on the objectsource during !PostBack and the RowEditing and RowUpdating events.

Any ideas why I can't capture the String content in these Cells?

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="PgimUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnShowPgim" runat="server"/>
         <div id="jsPgimPanel">
             <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="pgimObjectSource" Runat="server" TypeName="CarePlanModifier.Models.PgimMapping" SelectMethod="GetPgims" EnablePaging="True" SelectCountMethod="TotalNumberOfPgims" UpdateMethod="UpdatePgims" InsertMethod="UpdatePgims" DeleteMethod="SoftDeletePgims" OnUpdating="pgimObjectSource_Updating" OnSelecting="pgimObjectSource_Selecting" >
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:querystringparameter name="MatchCode" querystringfield="MatchCode" defaultvalue="0" />
                        <asp:querystringparameter name="CprId" querystringfield="CprId" defaultvalue="0" />
                        <asp:querystringparameter name="SessionUser" querystringfield="SessionUser" defaultvalue="0" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="Id"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="Icd1Code"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="MatchCode"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="Problems"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="Goals"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="Interventions"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Type="Int32" Name="CprId"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="EditUser"></asp:Parameter>
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
             <asp:GridView ID="gridPgim" Runat="server" DataSourceID="pgimObjectSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="White" CellPadding="3" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" pagesize="10" OnRowEditing="gridPgim_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridPgim_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gridPgim_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="gridPgim_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="Id, MatchCode,CprId, EditUser">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle  Font-Bold="True" BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="False" ></asp:CommandField>
                    <asp:BoundField Visible="false" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" DataField="Id" SortExpression="Id"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField Visible="false" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Icd1Code" DataField="Icd1Code" SortExpression="Icd1Code"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField Visible="false" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="MatchCode" DataField="MatchCode" SortExpression="MatchCode"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField Visible="false" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="CprId" InsertVisible="False" DataField="CprId" SortExpression="CprId"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField Visible="false" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="EditUser" InsertVisible="False" DataField="EditUser" SortExpression="EditUser"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Problems" SortExpression="Problems">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProblems" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" TextWrapping="Wrap" Rows="4"
                                   AcceptsReturn="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                    Text='<%# Bind("Problems") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEditProblems" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Problems") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Goals" SortExpression="Goals">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGoals" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" TextWrapping="Wrap" Rows="4" AcceptsReturn="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text='<%# Bind("Goals") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEditGoals" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Goals") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Interventions" SortExpression="Interventions">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInterventions" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" TextWrapping="Wrap" Rows="4" AcceptsReturn="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text='<%# Bind("Interventions") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEditInterventions" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Interventions") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
            </asp:GridView>
         </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jspanel.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scripts/jquery.jspanel.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scripts/jsglyph.css"/>
         <script type="text/javascript"> 
             var pgim;
             function clearPanel() {
                 //alert('0');
                 pgim.close();
                 //alert('1');
             };
             function displayPanel() {
                 //alert('0');
                 if (pgim != null) {
                     pgim.close();
                 }
                 //alert('1');
                pgim = $.jsPanel({
                    content: $('div#jsPgimPanel'),
                    title: "PGIM",
                    position: "center right",
                    theme: "light",
                    overflow: 'visible',
                    size: { width: 800, height: 450 },
                });
             };
             function rePanel() {
                 alert('3');
                 pgim.reloadContent();
                 alert('4');
             };
         </script>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gridDiagnoses" EventName="RowCommand"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the code-behind event methods:

```
protected void btnFindPgim_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    //PgimUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(new  PostBackTrigger{  ControlID=btn.UniqueID });
    PgimUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger { ControlID = btn.UniqueID, EventName = "Click" });
}

protected void gridPgim_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //Set the edit index.
    gridPgim.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    string diagCode = hdnSelectedDiagCode.Value;
    int cprId = Convert.ToInt32(hdnCprId.Value);

    CarePlanReview xCpr = (CarePlanReview)Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["xCpr"];
    displayFiles(Convert.ToInt32(hdnCprId.Value), xCpr.Client);

    //GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    //gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //gv.DataBind();

    BindPgimGrid(diagCode, cprId);

    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "jsPanel", "clearPanel();", true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "jsPanel", "displayPanel();", true);
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "jsPanel", "rePanel();", true);
}

protected void gridPgim_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    CarePlanReview xCpr = (CarePlanReview)Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["xCpr"];
    displayFiles(Convert.ToInt32(hdnCprId.Value), xCpr.Client);

    //Reset the edit index.
    gridPgim.EditIndex = -1;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "jsPanel", "clearPanel();", true);
}

protected void gridPgim_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    ISession session = HiHibernateUtil.GetCurrentSession();
    CarePlanReview xCpr = (CarePlanReview)Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["xCpr"];
    try
    {
        PgimMapping pm = new PgimMapping();
        if (e.NewValues["Problems"] != null)
        {
            pm.Problems = (string)e.NewValues["Problems"];
        }

        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            DataControlFieldCell cell = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i] as DataControlFieldCell;
            gv.Columns[i].ExtractValuesFromCell(e.NewValues, cell, DataControlRowState.Edit, true);
        }

        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in e.NewValues)
        {
            string dkey = (string)de.Key;
            if ( dkey.Equals("Icd1Code", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) )
            {
                pm.Icd1Code = (string)de.Value;
            }
            if (dkey.Equals("CprId", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                pm.CprId = Convert.ToInt32((string)de.Value);
            }
            if (dkey.Equals("MatchCode", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                pm.MatchCode = (string)de.Value;
            }
            if (dkey.Equals("MatchCode", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                pm.MatchCode = (string)de.Value;
            }
            if (dkey.Equals("Problems", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                pm.Problems = (string)de.Value;
            }
            if (dkey.Equals("Goals", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                pm.Goals = (string)de.Value;
            }
            if (dkey.Equals("Interventions", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                pm.Interventions = (string)de.Value;
            }
        }

        if (pm.CprId < 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("ERROR the 'cprId' value is invalid for " + pm.CprId);
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pm.Problems) || pm.Problems.Length < 3)
        {
            throw new Exception("ERROR the 'problem' value is empty for " + pm.MatchCode);
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pm.Goals) || pm.Goals.Length < 3)
        {
            throw new Exception("ERROR the 'goal' value is empty for " + pm.MatchCode);
        }

        pm.GmtOffset = Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("gmtOffset"));
        pm.Active = 0;
        pm.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
        pm.EditUser = xCpr.SessionUser.Username;

        // now add the PGIM to this Care Plan
        CareNeeds cneeds = new CareNeeds();
        cneeds.Active = 0;
        cneeds.CprId = pm.CprId;
        cneeds.EditUser = pm.EditUser;
        cneeds.GmtOffset = Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("gmtOffset"));
        cneeds.Goal = pm.Goals;
        cneeds.Problem = pm.Problems;
        cneeds.Interventions = pm.Interventions;
        cneeds.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;

        using (ITransaction txn = session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            session.Save(pm);
            session.Save(cneeds);

            txn.Commit();
        }

        //Reset the edit index.
        gridPgim.EditIndex = -1;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ee)
    {
        log.Error("gridPgim_RowUpdating()  " + ee.Message);
        log.Error("gridPgim_RowUpdating()  " + ee.StackTrace);
        LabelErrorMessages2.CssClass = "errorlabel";
        LabelErrorMessages2.Text = LabelErrorMessages.Text + " " + ee.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        session.Flush();
        session.Close();
    }
}

protected void gridPgim_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        BindPgimGrid(hdnSelectedDiagCode.Value, Convert.ToInt32(hdnCprId.Value));
        GridViewRow row = gridPgim.Rows[gridPgim.EditIndex];

    } else if ( e.CommandArgument == "Edit" )
    {

    }
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "jsPanel", "displayPanel();", true);
}
```

Finally, here is the DAL object (which is also mapped to a nHibernate mapping) but with some methods removed to shorten this post.

```
public class PgimMapping
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(PgimMapping));

    public PgimMapping(string diagCode, int cprId, string suser)
    {
        this.matchCode = diagCode;
        this.cprId = cprId;
        this.sessionUser = suser;
    }

    private string sessionUser = null;

    private string matchCode = null;
    public string MatchCode
    {
        get { return matchCode; }
        set { matchCode = value; }
    }

    private int id = 0;
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string icd1Code = null;
    public virtual string Icd1Code
    {
        get { return icd1Code; }
        set { icd1Code = value; }
    }

    private string icd9Code = null;
    public virtual string Icd9Code
    {
        get { return icd9Code; }
        set { icd9Code = value; }
    }

    private string description = null;
    public virtual string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    private string problems = null;
    public virtual string Problems
    {
        get { return problems; }
        set { problems = value; }
    }

    private string goals = null;
    public virtual string Goals
    {
        get { return goals; }
        set { goals = value; }
    }

    private string interventions = null;
    public virtual string Interventions
    {
        get { return interventions; }
        set { interventions = value; }
    }

    private string measures = null;
    public virtual string Measures
    {
        get { return measures; }
        set { measures = value; }
    }

    private string discussWDr = null;
    public virtual string DiscussWDr
    {
        get { return discussWDr; }
        set { discussWDr = value; }
    }

    private string memberProblems = null;
    public virtual string MemberProblems
    {
        get { return memberProblems; }
        set { memberProblems = value; }
    }

    private string memberGoals = null;
    public virtual string MemberGoals
    {
        get { return memberGoals; }
        set { memberGoals = value; }
    }

    private DateTime? addedDate = null;
    public virtual DateTime? AddedDate
    {
        get { return addedDate; }
        set { addedDate = value; }
    }

    private string editUser = null;
    public virtual string EditUser
    {
        get { return editUser; }
        set { editUser = value; }
    }

    private DateTime? modifyDate = null;
    public virtual DateTime? ModifyDate
    {
        get { return modifyDate; }
        set { modifyDate = value; }
    }

    private int gmtOffset = 0;
    public virtual int GmtOffset
    {
        get { return gmtOffset; }
        set { gmtOffset = value; }
    }

    private int active = 0;
    public virtual int Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set { active = value; }
    }

    private int cprId = 0;
    public int CprId
    {
        get { return cprId; }
        set { cprId = value; }
    }

    public void UpdatePgims(int Id, string Icd1Code, string MatchCode, int CprId, string Problems, string Goals, string Interventions, string EditUser)
    {

        ISession session = HiHibernateUtil.GetCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            if (CprId < 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("ERROR the 'cprId' value is invalid for " + CprId);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Problems) || Problems.Length < 3)
            {
                throw new Exception("ERROR the 'problem' value is empty for " + MatchCode);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Goals) || Goals.Length < 3)
            {
                throw new Exception("ERROR the 'goal' value is empty for " + MatchCode);
            }
            PgimMapping pm = new PgimMapping(Icd1Code, CprId, EditUser);
            pm.GmtOffset = Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("gmtOffset"));
            pm.Goals = Goals;
            pm.Problems = Problems;
            pm.Interventions = Interventions;
            pm.Icd1Code = Icd1Code;
            pm.Active = 0;
            pm.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
            pm.CprId = CprId;
            pm.MatchCode = MatchCode;
            pm.sessionUser = EditUser;

            // now add the PGIM to this Care Plan
            CareNeeds cneeds = new CareNeeds();
            cneeds.Active = 0;
            cneeds.CprId = CprId;
            cneeds.EditUser = EditUser;
            cneeds.GmtOffset = Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("gmtOffset"));
            cneeds.Goal = Goals;
            cneeds.Problem = Problems;
            cneeds.Interventions = Interventions;
            cneeds.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;

            using (ITransaction txn = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(pm);
                session.Save(cneeds);
                txn.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            log.Error("UpdatePgims()  " + ee.Message);
            log.Error("UpdatePgims()  " + ee.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            session.Flush();
            session.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I needed (although not exactly as I hoped and with many compromises) with the following bit of code.

```
protected void gridPgim_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        ISession session = HiHibernateUtil.GetCurrentSession();
        CarePlanReview xCpr = (CarePlanReview)Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["xCpr"];
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridPgim.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
            TableCellCollection tbc = row.Cells;
            Object[] objArray = new Object[row.Cells.Count];
            tbc.CopyTo(objArray, 0);
            DataControlFieldCell problemsCf = (DataControlFieldCell)objArray[Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("pgimProblemIndex"))];
            //String txtProb = ((Label)problemsCf.Controls[1]).Text;
            String txtProb = problemsCf.Text;
            DataControlFieldCell goalCf = (DataControlFieldCell)objArray[Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("pgimGoalIndex"))];
            //String txtGoal = ((Label)goalCf.Controls[1]).Text;
            String txtGoal = goalCf.Text;
            DataControlFieldCell interventionCf = (DataControlFieldCell)objArray[Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("pgimInterventionIndex"))];
            //String txtInt = ((Label)interventionCf.Controls[1]).Text;
            String txtInt = interventionCf.Text;
            DataControlFieldCell diagCode = (DataControlFieldCell)objArray[Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("pgimDiagIndex"))];
            String txtdiag = diagCode.Text;

            int cprId = Convert.ToInt32(hdnCprId.Value);

            // now add the PGIM to this Care Plan
            CareNeeds cneeds = new CareNeeds();
            cneeds.Active = 0;
            cneeds.CprId = cprId;
            cneeds.EditUser = xCpr.SessionUser.Username;
            cneeds.GmtOffset = Convert.ToInt32(Utility.getAppSetting("gmtOffset"));
            cneeds.Goal = txtGoal;
            cneeds.Problem = txtProb;
            cneeds.Interventions = txtInt;
            cneeds.Icd1Code = txtdiag;
            cneeds.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;

            using (ITransaction txn = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(cneeds);

                txn.Commit();
            }

            careNeedsDataSource.SelectParameters.Clear();
            careNeedsDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("CprId", System.Data.DbType.Int32, Convert.ToString(cprId));
            careNeedsDataSource.Select();
            careNeedsDataSource.DataBind();
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "jsPanel", "clearPanel();", true);
    }
```